# why object1 equals call instance of method instead of declaration object type

Tags: java

why object1 equals call instance of method instead of declaration object type
I have write code below. confution with `EQUAL object`

```
public class TestEqual {

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            return true;
        }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestEqual test1=new TestEqual();
            TestEqual test2=new TestEqual();
            if(test1.equals(test2))
            {
                System.out.println("EQUAL");
            }
            Object object1=new TestEqual();
            Object object2=new TestEqual();
            if(object1.equals(object2))
            {
                System.out.println("EQUAL object");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
EQUAL
EQUAL object
```

Comment: why is it referring TestEqual method instad  of object's equal method?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've overridden the `equals()` method in the `TestEqual`.

```
Object object1=new TestEqual();
```

And since the `equals()` (of the `Object` class) is [overridden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) in the `TestEqual`, even the `object1` will call it.

---

And if your doubt is regarding this statement, `Object object2=new TestEqual();`, then it is because, even though the reference is of type `Object`, the actual instance assigned to the reference is of `TestEqual()` only and thus the `equals()` of `TestEqual` is called.

In case you want to call the `Object` class's `equals()` method, you can try something like this

```
Object object3=new Object();
if(object3.equals(object2)) {
    System.out.println("EQUAL 1 object"); // this won't get printed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior, and how inheritance works. To learn more about how it works, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals(Object obj`) method need be like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
               return true;
       if (obj == null)
               return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
               return false;
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all the methods in java are virtual. So they are determined at the run time.
As you have overriden the equals method in you class the compiler sees that the Object class has an equals method so it compiles fine. But at the runtime, it sees that the Object class reference is referring to the TestEqual class object so it calls the equals method of TestEqual class.

This kind of behavior is called as Dynamic Polymorphism in java.

Comment: "By default" implies there's a way to change this behavior; there isn't. Instance methods are _always_ virtual in Java. (Static methods never are.)

Answer (score 0):

Always remember,instance methods are called based on the type of "OBJECT" not on the type of "REFERENCE" to an object. In your case,

```
    TestEqual test1=new TestEqual();
    TestEqual test2=new TestEqual();
```

And

```
    Object object1=new TestEqual();
    Object object2=new TestEqual();
```

Are creating instances of TestEqual class. So, only the equals() method of the object (not the reference) is called. Now, since the objects are same, the method which is being called will also be the same..